# DOT NET framework version in Habitat 1.7 for Sitecore 9.1

Tags: habitat

I installed Habitat 1.7 for Sitecore 9.1. Whenever I open web.config file of any module, its showing DOT NET framework as

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
</system.web>
```

But when I right click on any project file and check properties, its showing me .NET framework version as 4.7.1?

[image]

Why there are two different .NET version for Habitat modules?

Comment: It has to be 4.7.1 for 9.1. So the web.config is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug / missed update in the Habitat release for Sitecore 9.1. The `targetFramework` should be **4.7.1**, as it is in the assembly build configuration. It's now been logged as an [issue in the Habitat GitHub repo](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/issues/461). Thanks for pointing it out.